# How to get the current upload and download speeds in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want the terminal to output the current upload and download speeds of my network connection. I do not want to monitor the speeds in real time. I just want a "static" value to be able to write it in a file.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oddly the easiest way seems to be looking at `/proc/net/dev`. I've written the following to compare that file twice (with a second delay) and then to subtract the total bytes values. In this case `em1` is the network adaptor so just change that to whatever you need to look at.

```
awk '/em1/ {i++; rx[i]=$2; tx[i]=$10}; END{print rx[2]-rx[1] " " tx[2]-tx[1]}' \
 <(cat /proc/net/dev; sleep 1; cat /proc/net/dev)
```

The output is two numbers. Received bytes per second followed by sent bytes per second.

Comment: There we go. Boiled it down into one awk statement. Bootiful.

Comment: Worth mention that '/em1/' should be changed to '/<part of your interface name>/'

Answer (score 12):

Here's a variation  on Oli's excellent solution:

```
awk '{if(l1){print $2-l1,$10-l2} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' \
  <(grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev)
```

It will print the same result as Oli's approach:

```
$ awk '{if(l1){print $2-l1,$10-l2} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' \
>   <(grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev)
401500 30286
```

The first value is the download rate in bytes per second and the second is the upload rate. You could get a more human-friendly format with:

```
$ awk '{if(l1){print ($2-l1)/1024"kB/s",($10-l2)/1024"kB/s"} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' \
    <(grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev)
398.771kB/s 82.8066kB/s
```

Comment: Note: on Ubuntu 18.04 I had to use `wlp1s0` instead of `wlan0`. I won't edit the answer because I know this depends on the distro.