# How to measure download speed

Tags: software-recommendation

What is a good simple easily installable app to measure download speed on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Something like this: [How to get the current upload and download speeds in terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450604/how-to-get-the-current-upload-and-download-speeds-in-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

indicator-sysmonitor i think its the best one you can monitor your net speed at your top panel

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexeftimie/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

after installing go to options and replace the {cpu} and {ram} with {net} it can also be added to startup applications

New net-speed indicator for Ubuntu 14.04 Works great

indicator-netspeed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed
```

You can see your download speed in the top panel and this takes less space in top panel.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just visit **speedtest.net**. No installation necessary.